# Vue.js SPA : how to prevent browser from opening cached version if JWT has expired?

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, jwt

I have a problem that I can't solve with my Vue.js / Express application.

The process is as follows:

An unauthenticated user logs into the application and receives the login page.
Once authenticated, the backend generates and sends a cookie containing a JWT and the static content of the built Vue.js page.

Subsequently, calls to the REST API are made on the same backend that checks the validity of the JWT. When the JWT has expired, the static content of the login page is returned.

It works fine, but when the browser is closed and then reopened, if the tab has been kept in memory and the JWT has expired in the meantime, you end up with a cached version of the index page while the REST requests fail since the JWT has expired.

How do I get to the login page in this case? Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: The vuejs SPA (html, css, and frontend js) might be cached, but the data will all be fetched from HTTP calls when the application loads, so is there actually an instance where stale data might be displayed. If your first HTTP call to fetch some data fails because the JWT is no longer valid, you can just redirect them to the log in page. If you're storing sensitive information on the client through local storage then I think your question probably needs a bit more detail.

Comment: "If your first HTTP call to fetch some data fails because the JWT is no longer valid, you can just redirect them to the log in page."

In fact, that's the way it works, until the browser is closed and then reopened (and the JWT has expired in the meantime).
Failed API requests receive the login page, but not the main request to the index page.
Strangely, the request to the index page has no status in the console (not even 304 that I could have understood), and the answer is the <noscript> tag on the page....
If I refresh the page at that time, no problem I receive the login page.

Comment: I see, this is a pretty standard thing, I think most applications that deal with this end up making quite a few api calls when the application is open and running so it falls over pretty quickly rather than waiting for the user to interact with it. If it's not an issue that they can see the information (which they could see before hand anyway) then I wouldn't attempt to solve it, otherwise you'll be getting into the realm of heartbeat pings which could cause load issues as you scale.

Comment: That obviously assumes there's no regulations you're attempting to follow, if that's the case then perhaps a heartbeat is a reasonable idea. But likewise a JWT is meant to be quite long lived usually so you probably won't see the effect of an expiration 99% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved it by disabling cache on the backend side :

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private')
  next()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The good thing is that the requests fail. Depending on the request response, you should just redirect the user to the login page in the front application.

Here is the scenario :

Request => authenticated ? index : login